# how to change keyboard style programmatically in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4, ios13

I would like to change the keyboard style.
I have attached two pictures one the current situation and the second one is the desired situation.

[image: This image is of current keyboard style.]

[image: This is desired keyboard style.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this to change the keyboard type:

```
self.someTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.decimalPad
```

and for number with special character try this :-

```
UIKeyboardType.numbersAndPunctuation
```

from :- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinputtraits#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIKeyboardType

Comment: let me check that.

Comment: sure it will open number-pad

Comment: don't want to open the number pad. just check the above image

Comment: @ap00724 it's better to open number pad but just replace `UIKeyboardType.decimalPad` to `UIKeyboardType.numbersAndPunctuation`

Answer (score 1):

well thanks for suggetions and answers .

i found the solution for it.

> for the numbers

```
textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.numbersAndPunctuation
```

> for the alphabets

```
textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.emailAddress
```

Answer (score -1):

[image]           -  Keyboard Type Suggestions

textField.keyboardType = .emailAddress

> After = . (Multiple Suggestions for keyboard type you can select according to your usage)